# Need help to improve latitude & longitude accuracy

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm using the below code:

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

Where `locationManager` is an object of class `CLLocationManager`.

When I'm extracting the lat & long as:

```
lat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longt=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

NSLog(@"latitude is:%@",lat);
NSLog(@"longitude is: %@", longt);
```

then it prints as:

> latitude is:30.6807   longitude is: 76.726

but I do need as

> Lat: 57.645800 Long: 11.896000

As you see the decimal ends with 00 in both cases.

How can I do that??

Thanks

iPhoneDeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using

```
lat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
longt=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

as latitude and longitude are returned as double.

Answer (score 0):

use NSNumber to store the latitude and longitude. then in NSLog use %f and doubleValue property of NSNumber. NSNumber or NSDecimalNumber will give you maximum precision.